# Rails ActiveAdmin not Working on Heroku but works on Localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, activeadmin

I installed ActiveAdmin gem on an existing project, and I was able to Login on Localhost and following the documentation everything works perfectly on localhost. 
But on Heroku I can't login.
After running `heroku run rake db:seed` I can't login with the usual.

```
Email: admin@example.com 
Password: password
```

I am getting the following error

```
Invalid Email or password.
```

Any Idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Try `heroku run rake db:setup`

Comment: @MayurShah This didn't work, I got the following error. 
` FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"d3rbq23ov7k6h2", "username"=>"wphrizjyufkvla", "password"=>"bb4c097cafda117b1b83288cb34f9a80e386ba846bbce8c7eda2afed6827287a", "port"=>5432, "host"=>"ec2-54-163-254-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com"} 
rake aborted!
 `

Comment: @puneet18 I answered the question. None of this was the problem and didn't fix it either. But thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: @mayorsanmayor You should fix your issue of `heroku login` on your terminal. It helps you in future.

Comment: There was no issue with heroku login in the terminal actually. Try to create a new rails app and push it to heroku, then test some of the commands you know. You will notice that some priviledges have been removed for free users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work. The problem was in the db/seed.rb file. 
Looks like Heroku removed access for free users to access the console from the terminal. So `heroku run rake or rails console` didn't work.

Earlier I didn't read the code in the seed file till the end. Here is it:

```
AdminUser.create!(email: 'admin@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password') if Rails.env.development?
```

This means the sample AdminUser created is meant to work only in development environment. 
It became a production environment the moment it was pushed on heroku. 
And since I cannot go into the rails console through Heroku. 
I had to add a new line in the seed file like so:

```
AdminUser.create!(email: 'admin@whateveryouwantyoursitetobe.com', password: 'SomePassword', password_confirmation: 'SomePassword')
```

Now re-push this to heroku. And run `heroku run rake db:seed`

Now the new AdminUser details will work on your whateveryouwantyoursitetobe.com/admin

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

1. `heroku restart`
2. `heroku pg:reset DATABASE` or `heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL` # resets the db
3. `heroku run rake db:setup`

**note**: must specify DATABASE as above,You don't need to worry about `DATABASE_URL` (it's an environment variable set on Heroku)

Comment: 1 - 2 worked, even destroyed my database, but the 3rd still didn't work. 
Got the same error as before: 
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.

Comment: what about  `heroku run rake db:create` and `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: @mayorsanmayor try this command as well `rake db:schema:load`

Comment: I answered the question. None of this was the problem and didn't fix it either. But thank you very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Have You try This after push to heroku???

```
heroku run rake db:create

 heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I already answered the question. This was not the problem.